# Get SonarQube analysis results in JavaConsole

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

is it possible to get the results of a SonarQube analysis displayed in the JavaConsole?
For example, I installed SonarQube in Java/Maven. I can analyze my program and it uploads the results to localhost:9000. But can I get the number of "code-smells" or "bugs" in my console from the project when it got uploaded to localhost:9000?

I tried smth with

`HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?pageSize=500&componentKeys=CODE_SMELLS");`

But it seems like it does not work?

I tried to use the web/API but I don't understand the documentation. For example

web_api/api/measures

I don't know how to actually use it in the code I can not find an example or which method or so I have to use, to use the API.

Can someone maybe provide some example code or pseudocode for Java how I could retrieve results from the analysis? 
I am fairly new to SonarQube and how to work with an API. So sorry about that.

I am using the newest SonarQube free edition, maven and IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the [sonarlint](https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/) plugin you get the lint tab next to console and terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> on your project at root and that will produce the results

Comment: Okay nice, but I have to use a GET request via Java and the WebAPI but currently I don't rly get it which URL I have to use, when the project is called 'Sonar-Results'

I wanted to use a GET request:

would this be the right URL?

http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?pageSize=500&componentKeys=Sonar-Results

Answer (score 0):

On `http://localhost:9000/api/webservices/list` I could find all possible services and parameters.

This helped me a lot, for example:

`http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?componentKeys=myProjectKey&facets=types&facetMode=count`

[image]